# Decode Base64 image coming from MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, react-native, image, base64

I have on a MongoDB collection objects that have the attributes firstname, lastname, and picture. The picture attribute is a base64 encoded picture and the idea is that my python script can recognize faces in this picture, but since we cannot put pictures straight to the database, we are encoding it in the front-end and then sending it to the database encoded. Is there a better way for this to be done? FYI, the front-end is being done in React Native.

Comment: Have you thought about storing the images in aws s3 or similar and storing the metadata of the image (i.e location) in mongoDB. When reading in python, you can access the location metadata and then use the aws API to fetch the image?

Comment: that was our first thought, but in the front-end our images are being received as an URI, so we don't have the actual image files to upload them to AWS or something similar (idk if this explanation was very clear sorry)

Comment: Hmm, so can we not store the URI in mongoDB then read the URI into python and use urllib.request library in python to fetch the image?

Comment: it's not a URL tho, it's an URI, does that still work?

Comment: I'd assume so since URL is just a subset of URI. `import urllib.request` `imgURL = "http://<...>/image.jpg"` `urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgURL, "images/local-image.jpg")`

Comment: It says the system could not find the path specified

Comment: Python has several [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) decoding functions.  Have you tried those?

Comment: Yes, I have used most of the ones I can find, the image never creates properly, it either creates itself corrupted or it doesn't create with the correct image (it just generates a bunch of squares and not the original image)

Comment: Do you know the images are being stored properly?  For example, at the point where the image is encoded, if it is decoded there, is the image still intact?  Do you have a document with a small "test" image you could share?  BTW, without a `@rickhg12hs` in your comment I will not receive a notification since there are comments from multiple users.

Comment: It might also be helpful to show the code that base64 encodes the image, stores the image in the MongoDB server, retrieves the document from the MongoDB server, and attempts to base64 decode the image.